# How add item and value to dict by javascript?

Tags: javascript, dictionary, object

I have a `dict` as below shown. I want to add new item parallel with `info`. How can I do that? Thanks in advance.

Existing Dict:

```
Supermarket:{
    Food:{
        Fruit: {},
        Meat:{
            'info':{
                price: '20',
                },
        }
    }
}
```

New Dict:

```
Supermarket:{
    Food:{
        Fruit: {},
        Meat:{
            'info':{
                price: '20',
                },
            'place':{
                country: 'USA',
                },
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please share what have you tried? Some code snippet will help us understand your question better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript is prety straight forward in property or behavior inject
You directly use `.` operator and square brackets with numbers/words for objects `[0]` or `['place']`

So in your case to inject anything to anything, you simply use `.` and square bracket with corresponding existing/new propertly name `['place']`

```
 SuperMarket.Food.Meat['place'] = {country: 'USA'}
```

if the value is assigned to a variable say `var data =` then

```
 data.SuperMarket.Food.Meat['place'] = {country: 'USA'}
```